# PHP find matching property values in an array of objects

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array of custom objects and I want to find the objects who have matching property values.

This is my object.php:

```
class game_list
{
    var $team_name;
    var $field_nr;
    var $time;

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getTeamName()
    {
        return $this->team_name;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $team_name
     */
    public function setTeamName($team_name)
    {
        $this->team_name = $team_name;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getFieldNr()
    {
        return $this->field_nr;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $field_nr
     */
    public function setFieldNr($field_nr)
    {
        $this->field_nr = $field_nr;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getTime()
    {
        return $this->time;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $time
     */
    public function setTime($time)
    {
        $this->time = $time;
    }
}
```

So I have an array with x number of these objects. I want to find objects which have the same `$field_nr` and `$time` values. For example:

If two objects on my array, X and Y, both have `$field_nr = 1` and `$time = "12:00"` I want to print out "Match!".

This is what I am doing currently:

```
//getPlaySchedule returns my array($feedback) of objects
$feedback= getPlaySchedule($cup_name, $cup_year, $division);

for($x=0; $x<count($feedback); $x++){
    $time = $feedback[$x]->getTime();
    $field = $feedback[$x]->getFieldNr();
    $team = $feedback[$x]->getTeamName();

    for($y=0; $y<count($feedback); $y++){
        if($time == $feedback[$y]->getTime() && $field == $feedback[$y]->getFieldNr() && $team != $feedback[$y]->getTeamName()){

            echo 'Match!';
        }
    }
}
```

My solution, however, prints out "Match!" two times for each match. Is there a better way of finding these matches in my object array?

Marcus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you not store, what you've checked, and every time loop through the whole array. For example, if you have object A,B,C,D,E,F, first check the A. Let say, A will match D. When you check D, D will match A.

So you need to store it into an array, or insert a pointer, what objects checked already, and when checkin D, skip A, B, C.

A possible solution, if you set a counter, in my example `$z`, and start the second loop from that. This prevent the script to check again what you've already checked. Code not tested.

```
$z = 0;
for ($x = 0; $x < count($my_array); $x++) {
    $time = $feedback[$x]->getTime();
    $field = $feedback[$x]->getFieldNr();
    $team = $feedback[$x]->getTeamName();
    for ($y = $z; $y < count($my_array); $y++) {
        if ($time == $feedback[$y]->getTime() && $field == $feedback[$y]->getFieldNr() && $team != $feedback[$y]->getTeamName()) {
            echo 'Match!';
        }
    }
    $z++;
}
```